# How can i trigger click event where URL matching the link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger a click event if URL query string matches a link on a page 
Example URL

> https://www.website.com/video?v=9rqSjXX-eoo

Based on query string i am creating the whole URL for match

matchURL = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/9rqSjXX-eoo?showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1`

Example Video list

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D91liF_Ml-M?showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1">Video One</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9rqSjXX-eoo?showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1">Video Two</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EReqWOWUNxU?showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1">Video Three</a>
</div>
```

If query string matches any link the it should trigger click event for that link in our case it should click second link as it matches the querystring

Comment: The query string in your example doesn't match anything in the example HTML. The value of `v` matches a segment of the value of on of the `href`s though.

Comment: It does please check `embed/9rqSjXX-eoo/` its the second url. Let me refrase it to part of URL, In my actual problem i am recreating the url

Answer (score 1):

A super simple approach would be to iterate over the a tags and perform an indexOf of the query string.

The example below will only work if you have one query string key attached as per your example. Otherwise you'll need to do a more clever query parameter extraction.

```
var url = 'https://www.website.com/video?v=9rqSjXX-eoo';

$("a").each(function() {
        var query = url.split("?v=")[1];

    if (this.href.indexOf(query) != -1) {
        $(this).get(0).click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Will this match part of href of whole URL need to match

Comment: can we use ` $(this).click(function (e) { });` instead of `$(this).get(0).click();`

Comment: How can the whole url match if your samples are not even close to being similar apart from the query string. Your search is made using a query string comparison unless both links are the same. Currently one has a different domain and a different path. I think even if you need them to match, go ahead and build your string yourself. My answer is as per your question. And no, you can't use `$(this).click()` on a hyperlink, hence why I get the node element.

Answer (score 0):

Compare two links and if its true the fire the following  :

```
window.location.href = matchURL ; //browser refreshes and load the requested url
```

Comment: Why is this upvoted? This does not trigger anything, question did not ask for a how to redirect to url nor does it present how to match the urls. Not even partially is this answer complete.

Comment: result is still same .